# How do you skip a row when an error occurs

Tags: java, try-catch, addition

With my application you can select a csv file and read that data as a map (they are coordinates). Now I want if someone has wrong data in their csv that I skip that data line.

I thought to solve this with try catch but I can't figure it out. I only want to add the line if the data is also correct, otherwise I want to go to the next line and see if it is correct and then add it if the line is valid.

```
private static ArrayList<ScanDataObject> getCsvData(String pathToCsv) {
    ArrayList<ScanDataObject> csvDataArray = new ArrayList<>();
    ScanDataObject scanData = new ScanDataObject("0", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    boolean isCorrectCSVdata = true;

    if (pathToCsv.length() > 0) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(pathToCsv))) {
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                //              Create an array of strings with all the items in the current line
                String[] splits = scanner.nextLine().split(";");

                try {
                    String dateTime = splits[0];
                    double xAxis = Double.parseDouble(splits[1].replace(',', '.'));
                    double yAxis = Double.parseDouble(splits[2].replace(',', '.'));
                    double zAxis = Double.parseDouble(splits[3].replace(',', '.'));
                    double distance = Double.parseDouble(splits[4].replace(',', '.'));
                    double xAxisRover = Double.parseDouble(splits[5].replace(',', '.'));
                    double yAxisRover = Double.parseDouble(splits[6].replace(',', '.'));

                    //              Create a new ScanDataObject to save the newly read information and add to the ArrayList afterwards
                    scanData = new ScanDataObject(dateTime, xAxis, yAxis, zAxis, distance, xAxisRover, yAxisRover);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    isCorrectCSVdata = false;
                }
                
                if(isCorrectCSVdata = true) {
                    csvDataArray.add(scanData);
                }
                
                isCorrectCSVdata = true;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return csvDataArray;
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can use `continue;` in a loop to end the current iteration early and start the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do all the parsing in a try-catch and then have a `continue` in the catch.

If you then put the `csvDataArray.add(scanData);` at the end of the read-loop it will not add data from a line in which an error occoured, you already thought ahead and put the declaration of scanData outside of the try-catch, so it should work without major refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have an error with single '=' sign in if statement. And condition is always true because of that.

Instead

```
if(isCorrectCSVdata = true) {
```

You should write

```
if(isCorrectCSVdata == true) {
```

or just

```
if(isCorrectCSVdata) {
```